# Use an older python version in Ubuntu when executing a binary from Java using ProcessBuilder

Tags: python, java, ubuntu, conda

I have a Java SpringBoot app that does audio processing and builds to a docker container based on Ubuntu. The app uses a third-party binary tool (https://github.com/shaka-project/shaka-packager) like

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder();
pb.command("shaka-packager", "-input foo", "-output bar");
pb.start().waitFor();
```

Problem:
We started updating versions of Java, etc, and are using a newer version of Ubuntu 22.04, which comes with Python 3.10. This broke shaka-packager, because it has some python component that does `from collections import Mapping`, which has been deprecated and moved to `collections.abc`.

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way I can run the shaka packager in a virtual 3.9 python environment. I messed around with conda for a bit, but can't seem to get it to work with Java's `ProcessBuilder` calls. `conda activate` works in interactive shells, but `ProcessBuilder` creates a new shell for every invocation. I thought `conda run` would do it, but it seems to only work with python scripts and not compiled binaries.

Any suggestions on how to approach this? I could fork shaka packager and fix the python script that's failing (and submit a PR), but I would prefer not maintaining our own fork long-term if the owner doesn't merge it. I would also love to move away from a binary and use a Java library instead, but haven't found one that does everything shaka can do and I don't think I have the time to experiment with a mix of different libraries to get full feature parity.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to install Python3.9 from PPA:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
$ sudo apt install python3.9
```

Now you can use `python3.9`:

```
$ python3.9 --version
$ python3.9 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: But the binary would continue using the default system python unless I replace the symbolic link, wouldn't it? Why would it start calling `python3.9`?

Comment: Because you will have two binaries now: one for the system and one for python3.9 (with its own packages).

Comment: I meant the third-party shaka packager binary that needs python 3.9. It's just calling `python` internally, not `python3.9`

Comment: OK. Maybe you can use `update-alternatives` to change the default python interpreter